# Error al leer archivo binario y mostrarlo por consola en Java

Tags: java, lista

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo binario y mostrarlo por consola.

Tengo una clase **Producto** bastante sencilla es la siguiente.

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private double precio;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

    Producto (String id, String nombre, String descripcion, double precio) {
        this.id = id ;
        this.nombre = nombre ;
        this.descripcion = descripcion ;
        this.precio= precio ;
    }


    public String getId () {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getNombre () {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion () {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public double getPrecio () {
        return this.precio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format ("{id:%s, nombre:%s, descripcion:%s, precio:%.2f}",
                this.id, this.nombre, this.descripcion, this.precio);
    }

}
```

Luego, el archivo que quiero leer es un .dat con objetos de la clase **Producto** pero está guardado con una estructura tipo **LinkedList**

```
[{id:0001, nombre:caja, descripcion:caja de tipo 1, precio:10,50}, {id:0002, nombre:tornillo, descripcion:tornillo de tipo 1, precio:0,50}, {id:0003, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 1, precio:0,15}, {id:0004, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 2, precio:0,14}, {id:0005, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 3, precio:0,17}, {id:0006, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 4, precio:0,17}, {id:0007, nombre:tornillo, descripcion:tornillo de tipo 2, precio:0,55}, {id:0008, nombre:arandela, descripcion:arandela de tipo 1, precio:0,11}, {id:0012, nombre:arandela, descripcion:arandela de tipo 3, precio:0,21}, {id:0014, nombre:caja, descripcion:caja de tipo 2, precio:12,99}]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es leer ese archivo binario que contiene un LinkedList, pasarlo a un List e imprimirlo por consola.
Para que quede así:

```
*CONTENIDO DEL ARCHIVO BINARIO
-----------------------------
Total de productos: 10
PRODUCTO  1: {id:0001, nombre:caja, descripción:caja de tipo 1, precio:10,50}
PRODUCTO  2: {id:0002, nombre:tornillo, descripción:tornillo de tipo 1, precio:0,50}
PRODUCTO  3: {id:0003, nombre:tuerca, descripción:tuerca de tipo 1, precio:0,15}
PRODUCTO  4: {id:0004, nombre:tuerca, descripción:tuerca de tipo 2, precio:0,14}
PRODUCTO  5: {id:0005, nombre:tuerca, descripción:tuerca de tipo 3, precio:0,17}
PRODUCTO  6: {id:0006, nombre:tuerca, descripción:tuerca de tipo 4, precio:0,17}
PRODUCTO  7: {id:0007, nombre:tornillo, descripción:tornillo de tipo 2, precio:0,55}
PRODUCTO  8: {id:0008, nombre:arandela, descripción:arandela de tipo 1, precio:0,11}
PRODUCTO  9: {id:0012, nombre:arandela, descripción:arandela de tipo 3, precio:0,21}
PRODUCTO 10: {id:0014, nombre:caja, descripción:caja de tipo 2, precio:12,99}*
```

He intentado varias cosas disparatadas, una solución me da error, otra solo me muestra en una línea todos los productos.

```
/**
 * Clase que lee de un fichero binario, donde se grabó una list de objetos
 * Producto y muestra el contenido de lo leído por consola.
 */
public class BinarioProductosToConsola {

    /**
     * Método principal
     *
     * @param args argumentos de la línea de ordenes
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream input;
        ObjectInputStream salida;
        LinkedList<Producto> list = null;
        Producto objetoProductos;
        List lista = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("productos_entrada.dat");
            salida = new ObjectInputStream(input);


            while(true){
                Object data = salida.readObject();
                LinkedList<Producto> producto = (LinkedList <Producto>) data;
                lista.add(producto);
                System.out.println(lista);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```

También he probado esto, pero el mismo error:

```
try {
        input = new FileInputStream("productos_entrada.dat");
        salida = new ObjectInputStream(input);

        while (true) {
            objetoProductos = (Producto) salida.readObject();
            objetoProductos.toString();
            lista.add(objetoProductos);
        }

    }catch(EOFException e){

    }
```

También:

```
try {

            input = new FileInputStream("productos_entrada.dat");
            salida = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            list = (LinkedList<Producto>) salida.readObject();
            List<Producto> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list);

            System.out.println(list1);

        } catch (EOFException e) {
            return;
        }
```

Pero el resultado es:

```
[{id:0001, nombre:caja, descripcion:caja de tipo 1, precio:10,50}, {id:0002, nombre:tornillo, descripcion:tornillo de tipo 1, precio:0,50}, {id:0003, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 1, precio:0,15}, {id:0004, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 2, precio:0,14}, {id:0005, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 3, precio:0,17}, {id:0006, nombre:tuerca, descripcion:tuerca de tipo 4, precio:0,17}, {id:0007, nombre:tornillo, descripcion:tornillo de tipo 2, precio:0,55}, {id:0008, nombre:arandela, descripcion:arandela de tipo 1, precio:0,11}, {id:0012, nombre:arandela, descripcion:arandela de tipo 3, precio:0,21}, {id:0014, nombre:caja, descripcion:caja de tipo 2, precio:12,99}]
```

Hay algo que falla en mis bases de estructura de almacenamiento y genéricos y no logro sacarlo. Muchas gracias a quien pueda orientarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Hay algo que falla en mis bases de estructura de almacenamiento y genéricos ...

No es una falla del archivo, el problema radica en la forma como estás imprimiendo el contenido de la lista.

Esta línea de código:

```java
System.out.println(list1);
```

En realidad el compilador de Java lo transforma a:

```java
System.out.println(list1.toString());
```

Por lo tanto, estarías invocado al método `toString` de la clase `LinkedList`, que a su vez, este método recorre toda la lista a través de un bucle, en la cual, va accediendo a la referencia de cada objeto (en este caso de tipo `Producto`) y por último, invoca al método `toString` de la clase `Producto` y por esa razón te sale todo en una única línea, debido a que, la clase `LinkedList` tiene su propia implementación del método `toString`.

En fin, el último código que hiciste está bien, simplemente debes recorrer la lista manualmente.

Por ejemplo:

```java
try {

 input = new FileInputStream("productos_entrada.dat");
 salida = new ObjectInputStream(input);
 list = (LinkedList<Producto>) salida.readObject();
 List<Producto> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list);

 for(Producto pd : list1)
 {
    System.out.println(pd.toString() + "\n");
 }

} 
catch (EOFException e) 
{
      return;
}
```

No es necesario crear otra lista auxiliar, puedes usar el objeto al que apunta `list`.

```java
try {

 input = new FileInputStream("productos_entrada.dat");
 salida = new ObjectInputStream(input);
 list = (LinkedList<Producto>) salida.readObject();

 for(Producto pd : list)
 {
    System.out.println(pd.toString() + "\n");
 }

} 
catch (EOFException e)
{
      return;
}
```

**Recomendación:**

No agregues un `return` adentro del `catch`, debido a que, no sabrás cual es el error si es que llegara ocurrir una excepción. Así que lo recomendable sería añadir un `print` para poder visualizar el error.

Código java:

```java
try
{

 input = new FileInputStream("productos_entrada.dat");
 salida = new ObjectInputStream(input);
 list = (LinkedList<Producto>) salida.readObject();

 for(Producto pd : list)
 {
    System.out.println(pd.toString() + "\n");
 }

} 
catch (EOFException e)
{
      System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, funciona!